# Firebase UI Auth ProfileScreen is randomly throwing errors when failing to load the user avatar

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

This user avatar is very non-critical but is throwing an exception and halting up my app. It's happening in the library code so I can't even exception handle it gracefully. Has anyone encountered this and have a tip on how to get `ProfileScreen` to handle its own issues?

```
return Scaffold(
    body: ProfileScreen(),
    );
```

Sporadically will crash with the following trace...

```
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

Image provider:
  NetworkImage("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/<id>",
  scale: 1)
Image key:
  NetworkImage("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/<id>",
  scale: 1)
Error: HTTP request failed, statusCode: 403, https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/<id>
```

Being thrown in core file `_network_image_web.dart` when `firebase_ui_auth` is presumably calling `Image.network()` to load the avatar.

```
...
        final bool success =
            accepted || fileUri || notModified || unknownRedirect;

        if (success) {
          completer.complete(request);
        } else {
          completer.completeError(e);
          throw image_provider.NetworkImageLoadException( //<--------------------------
              statusCode: request.status ?? 400, uri: resolved);
        }
      }));
...
```

Also, when I go to the web address of the image in a browser, it's there.

Comment: Recommend that you submit this as an issue to their github repo.
 - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter

Comment: have you checked this URL: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/<id> ? .

Comment: @DewaPrabawa yes - see the last line of my original post